error: cannot assign a value to final variable android java
I am working on android project and I'm stuck on this error: cannot assign a value to final variable count.
I have used following code.
       public final Thread z = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (!WebScraper.this.i) {
            for (final int i = 0; i < 20 && !WebScraper.this.i; i++) {

                WebScraper.this.h.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            WebScraper.this.h.loadUrl(ChromeHelper.HeaderClick(i));
                        } catch (Exception unused) {
                        }
                    }
                });
                WebScraper webScraper = WebScraper.this;
                if (webScraper.y) {
                    webScraper.y = false;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                WebScraper.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        WebScraper.this.process44();
                    }
                });
                if (i >= 19) {
                    WebScraper.this.h.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                WebScraper.this.h.loadUrl(ChromeHelper.NextClicker);
                                WebScraper.this.h.clearCache(true);
                            } catch (Exception unused) {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e3) {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    WebScraper.this.h.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                WebScraper webScraper = WebScraper.this;
                                webScraper.w = webScraper.h.getUrl();
                            } catch (Exception unused) {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        WebScraper.deleteCache(WebScraper.this.getApplicationContext());
        WebScraper.this.startActivity(new Intent(WebScraper.this, LeadsContactsActivity.class));
        WebScraper.this.finish();
    }
});

Basically it is a project to extract B2B leads. I have tried to solve this error in different ways but I have not been successful.
Error is :
error: cannot assign a value to final variable i
for (final int i = 0; i < 20 && !WebScraper.this.i; i++) {

Why did you declare i to be final? You also have two i variables there.

You can see it in Try Catch >   WebScraper.this.h.loadUrl(ChromeHelper.HeaderClick(i));

WebScraper.this.i is a boolean value.

for (final int i = 0 ... i++) -- how should i be incremented if it is declared final ?

Please any suggestion.

i have used also this .      for (int i = 0; i < 20 && !WebScraper.this.i; i++) {
                int finalI = i;
                WebScraper.this.h.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            WebScraper.this.h.loadUrl(ChromeHelper.HeaderClick(finalI));
                        } catch (Exception unused) {
                        }


try with an auxiliary variable like for (int i = 0 ... i++) { final int j = i; and using j inside the Runnable

I have solved this by changing in my code.
     for (int i = 0; i < 20 && !WebScraper.this.i; i++) {
                final int j = i;
                WebScraper.this.h.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            WebScraper.this.h.loadUrl(ChromeHelper.HeaderClick(j));
                        } catch (Exception unused) {
                        }
                    }
                });

